# How to store sensitive data of different clients in SQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I work at a small company and I am trying to figure out a solution for storing sensitive data of multiple clients in Microsoft SQL server. Actually, I feel like this is a general database question and it is not specific to MSSQL.

Until now we have been using a proprietary database where the client data is stored as db files (flat files) in the client’s root directories in the file system. So the operating system permissions guarantee that the application used by client X can never fetch data from client Y’s database. Please note that there is no database server/instance/engine here…

However, for my project I want to use SQL database. But the security folks are expressing concerns over putting data of different clients on a single database.

One option is to create separate database instances for different clients. However, I am not sure if this idea is scalable.

So my questions are:

1) Is there any mechanism in MSSQL that enables you to store databases ‘separately’ in different files used by the SQL server?

2) Let’s say I have only one database instance where I have databases of client X and client Y. How can I make sure that client X’s requests can never (accidentally) get misdirected to client Y’s database? I do not want to rely on some parameter in my code to determine which database to fetch from! :)

So, is there any solid authentication scheme to guarantee that my queries could not be misdirected to fetch from an incorrect client table?

I think this is a very common problem and there has to be a good solution for this. What are other companies doing?

Please let me know if there are any good articles to read up on this.

Answer (score 1):

Different databases are always stored in different files in SQL Server so you don't even have to do anything special for this.  However, NTFS permissions will not help you in this case as the clients aren't ever accessing the files directly on disk.

One possible solution in SQL Server is to create separate sets of Windows user IDs and map those to separate SQL Logins for each customer.  You could then only assign those logins access to the appropriate databases.  For example, if you were hosting web sites for client X and client Y, you would set up the connection string(s) in the web.config for client X's web site to use the appropriate login(s) for client X's database.  Vice versa for client Y.  This guarantees that no matter what (barring a hard-coded login), the code from client X's site will never access client Y's database.

You can have 32,000 databases on a single instance of SQL server and having separate databases enables a number of improved serviceability scenarios (such as restoring a single customer's DB in case of a data problem without affecting all of your other customers).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful. I like the idea of creating separate SQL logins for each customer. But I din't understand why we need to create windows IDs? One more thing I din't mention here is the backend code is in C++. So I will need to think where to have the config files for each client to be able to create the connection strings appropriately before firing the query.

Comment: You don't need to create windows logins, you can use SQL Server logins as well.

Comment: Well for example if you were using IIS and ASP.NET web sites (just guessing here) you could have your app pools run as a customer-specific Windows service account user ID that only has the appropriate privileges for that customer's web site.  If the back-end code is C++, then perhaps you're using Windows services in which case it's for the same reason.  The alternative is that you'd be using a common Windows user ID to run all of your web sites or services? - this sounds like it doesn't fit your compartmentalization requirement.